# Give style to parent element when child element is hovered

Tags: html, css

i have a ul(parent) inside which another ul is there. I have given style to the child ul using the following code when hovering on the parent ul

```
ul:hover>ul{

}
```

This gives style to the child ul when hovering on the parent ul. Now I want to give style to the parent ul when hovering on the child ul?

Is there any posible way?

Comment: There's no parent selector till now.....

Comment: you should use jquery for that.

Comment: You cannot do that using the current css techniques. But css4 will have the parent selectors.
As of now we might be able to help you if you tell us your exact requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: use jquery
    $( "your child tag" ).focus(function() {
    $( this ).parent().css( "your css style" );
    });

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there is nothing like that in CSS. The spec for [CSS4 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) does include the subject selector, which would allow you to solve this problem like that:

```
!ul > li:hover { ... }
```

For now you'll have to use Javascript if you can't avoid this problem.

A jQuery way to do it:

```
$('ul').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).parent('ul').addClass('ishovered');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).parent('ul').removeClass('ishovered');
    }
});
```

With that you could use the `.ishovered` class to style your parent list via CSS.

Comment: Thanks! You're not wrong at all and your solution is fine. Your answer just lacks the explanation on *why* this solution is required.

Comment: thanks but I think I should not took -1. anyway I deleted my answer cause a person gave me a down vote without reason.

Comment: Well the opinion of one person doesn't make or break your answer. You weren't wrong after all.

Comment: you are right but I don't want to get downvotes. and I undelete it again. thanks anyway.